# How to loop to find specific text in elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following demo. Why am I not able to find and filter divs bases on their text?

```js
$(".list-group-item").each(function(){
       if($(this':contains("text")').contains("Map")){
          $(this).append(" - One");
       }
       if($(this':contains("text")').contains("Tap")){
          $(this).append(" - Two");
       }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Map</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">App</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Tap</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Map</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Wap</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your syntax `$(this':contains("text")'` is incorrect, try using [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/), like:

```
$(".list-group-item").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':contains("Map")')) {
        $(this).append(" - One");
    }
    if($(this).is(':contains("Tap")')) {
        $(this).append(" - Two");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing it as below

```
 $(".list-group-item").each(function(){
       if($(this).text() == "Map"){
          $(this).append(" - One");
       }
       if($(this).text() == "Tap"){
          $(this).append(" - Two");
       }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you may missed concat(+) between `this`:contains

```
$(".list-group-item").each(function(){
       if($(this + ':contains("text")').contains("Map")){
          $(this).append(" - One");
       }
       if($(this + ':contains("text")').contains("Tap")){
          $(this).append(" - Two");
       }
});
```